# Euclidean Connection and Constant Vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $\nabla$ be the Euclidean connection on a manifold $M = \mathbb{R}^n$. The definition I'm following is if $X, Y$ is are smooth vector fields on $M$ with $Y$ given by:
$$
Y = \sum_{i}^{n} Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$

Then the Euclidean connection is defined as:

$$
\nabla_Y X = \sum_{i}^{n} X(Y^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$

I want to show that given a curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow M $, a vector field whose euclidean connection with $\gamma'$ is $0$ has to be constant.

What I don't understand is how we can act on $\gamma^i$ with $X$ when $\gamma ^i$ is a map from $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ into $M$, unlike $Y^i$ which is  $C^\infty(M)$

Comment: When you define $\nabla_YX$, shouldn't that be $\nabla_XY$?  Usually a connection is $C^\infty(M)$-linear in the subscript.  This would also eliminate the issue your having.

Comment: You're totally right, thanks. That was silly on my part

Comment: @Aweygan If you'd like to post your comment I could mark it as the answer, I think I've figured out the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the Euclidean connection should be

$$\nabla_XY=\sum_{i}^{n} X(Y^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}.$$

(This makes $\nabla$ satisfy the standard definition of a connection.)  Using this, it should be easy to define $\nabla_{\gamma'}Y$ for a curve $\gamma$.